# Setting different default values in rails migrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, rails-migrations

I'm trying to write a migration and it looks something like this:

```
class AddStatusToWorks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :works do |t|
        t.string :status
    end
  end

  def self.down
    change_table :works do |t|
        t.remove :status
    end
  end
end
```

Thing is, I want to set different default values for "status" based on a boolean value that's already in the table, "complete." If complete = true, status = "complete." If not, status = "work in progress." (The reason I want a string instead of keeping complete as the boolean is because I want there to be able to be more than two possibilites for status.) Any idea how to do that? Do I just stick an if statement in there like this

```
change_table :works do |t|
        t.string :status
           if (:complete == true)
               :value => "complete"
           else
               :value => "wip"
end
```

Er, so that doesn't look quite right. I googled a bit and found that you can set :default values, but that's not quite what I'm going for. Any ideas/help would be lovely. Thanks!

Comment: So you want to initialize `status` based on the current value of `complete`? What about new rows?

Comment: Er...new rows? I am mildly clueless on this front, sorry.

Comment: Wait! Do you mean new rows as in future entries to the database? In those cases, the user would set a value whenever they create a new work. It's just that there are a lot of entries already in the database and I'd like to know if there's an automatic way to set their values.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean by *new rows*.

Comment: Heh, I knew I was missing something. But I caught on eventually, that counts for something, right? Looking over your other response now!

Comment: Yes it certainly does count for something, we're all here to learn after all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a default at all, you just need to add the new column and give it values. Something like this should work:

```
def self.up
  change_table :works do |t|
      t.string :status
  end
  Works.reset_column_information
  Works.where(:complete => true).update_all(:status => 'complete')
  Works.where(:complete => [false, nil]).update_all(:status => 'wip')
end
```

See the [Migrations Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#using-models-in-your-migrations) for information on `reset_column_information`.

You could also do it straight in the database but you have to be careful about different boolean representations (PostgreSQL wants `'t'` and `'f'`, MySQL wants `1` and `0`, SQLite wants `1` and `0` but Rails mistakenly uses `'t'` and `'f'`, ...):

```
t = connection.quote(true)
connection.execute(%Q{
  update works
  set status = case complete
    when #{t} then 'complete'
    else 'wip'
  end
})
```

Comment: So you can use "where" to pick out info, not if/else. Oh, that looks brilliant, exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: Right, you use `where` to tell ActiveRecord what you're looking for and then `update_all` to turn that into an `UPDATE ...` inside the database.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that default values are created immediately when the record is created, and thus don't yet have values for fields w/o defaults. You'll likely want to move this sort of logic to your model. Perhaps in an ActiveRecord callback, i.e. before_validation or before_save.

Comment: Ahh...hmm. Okay. So basically, create the table without the if statement and then in the model, do something like this:

`def edit_status
    if self.complete = true
       self.status = "complete"
    else
       self.status = "wip"`

then before_save :edit_status

Like that?

Comment: welp, that lost a lot of the formatting. Eh. At any rate, there is not way to do it directly in the migration? Because the thing is I want the default values to be set once and then the user can directly edit them after that. If I use before_save, won't that trigger every time the user edits anything about :works?