# Rails migration not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have strange problem. This is my migration code:

```
class SetDefaultToFalse < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    MyObject.where('done is ?', nil).each do |a|
      a.done = false
      a.save
    end
  end
end
```

If I run this on database dump from while ago, with all the other, older migrations, after it's done, any of the `my_objects` don't have `done` field marked as `false`. If I do `rake db:rollback` and `db:migrate` again, suddenly, it works. Why? Column `done` is added more then 5 migrations before this one. Changing previous migrations is not the solution i'm looking for.

Comment: You should have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12612969/setting-different-default-values-in-rails-migrations

Comment: @TarunJadhwani, You can post Your comment as answer. The solution were those two lines:
MyObject.connection.schema_cache.clear!
MyObject.reset_column_information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at this:

[Setting different default values in rails migrations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12612969/setting-different-default-values-in-rails-migrations)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why would you do that in a migration, but this might help:

```
MyObject.where('done is ?', nil).update_all(done: false)
```

Comment: Code in example was simplified to show only the problem in easy way. Operation presented there should be done with creating a field and 'default' option set to false.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try this code:

```
class SetDefaultToFalse < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    MyObject.where('done is ?', nil).each do |a|
      a.update_attribute(done: false)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

done field added after create. In db schema 'done' field not exist.

Run

> rake db:migrate